# Log4j: configure JDBC appender to use Datasource

Tags: log4j

I have to configure the JDBC appender to use a datasource..is it possible?

if so , how? 
My present file looks like so:

```
# Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, sql

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.sql.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.sql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.sql.user=root
log4j.appender.sql.password=password
# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.sql.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES ('%x', now() ,'%C','%p','%m')
# Define the xml layout for file appender
log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: Did you mean to lookup the datasource in the JNDI tree?

Comment: yes! I want to find it in the jndi tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a datasource, you need to add the jar file of [Apache Extras for Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) <sup>**1**</sup> and use the class [**`org.apache.log4j.DBAppender`**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DBAppender.html) <sup>**2**</sup>. e.g.:

```sh
# Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, sql

# Define the database appender
log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.DBAppender
log4j.appender.sql.connectionSource=org.apache.log4j.receivers.db.JNDIConnectionSource
log4j.appender.sql.connectionSource.jndiLocation=java:/comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDS
```

---

*Notes*

1. You can download the file `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar).
2. This appender uses a database schema (not customizable) and you can find it [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/log4j-extras/+/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/receivers/db/dialect/). If you want to use other tables, you'll need to rewrite the appender.

Comment: Hi Paul, my datasource is a bean with bean  id="datasource". How do I change the above properties file to read that

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11399305/870248 in order to bind your datasource to the JDNI tree.

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad Or you may want to see [Programmatically Configuring log4j](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.de/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html)

Comment: I have asked a similar question here. I think you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670449/log4j-custom-jdbc-appender-datasource