# Log4J2 JdbcAppender doesn't compose correct INSERT statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to log into PostgreSQL database with this pooled JDBC logger in my Spring app.

*Main idea comes from here: [How to initialize log4j with Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58871779/how-to-initialize-log4j-with-spring-boot-application)*

```
@Component
public class JdbcAppenderConfiguration implements 
                     ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  private static Logger LOGGER = 
      LogManager.getLogger(JdbcAppenderConfiguration.class);

  private final DataSource dataSource;

  public JdbcAppenderConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final ColumnConfig[] cc = {
        ColumnConfig.newBuilder()
            .setConfiguration(ctx.getConfiguration())
            .setName("level")
            .setPattern("%level")
            .setUnicode(false)
            .build()
    };

    final Appender appender = JdbcAppender
        .newBuilder()
        .setName("databaseAppender")
        .setIgnoreExceptions(false)
        .setConnectionSource(new ConnectionFactory(dataSource))
        .setTableName("logs2")
        .setColumnConfigs(cc)
        .build();

    appender.start();

    ctx.getConfiguration().addAppender(appender);

    final LoggerConfig loggerConfig =
        ctx.getConfiguration()
           .getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);

    ctx.updateLoggers();

  }

}
```

And connection factory:

```
public class ConnectionFactory extends AbstractConnectionSource {

  private final DataSource dataSource;

  public ConnectionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    AssertUtils.notNull(dataSource, "dataSource");
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
  }

}
```

But while logging I get this error:

> 2020-12-12 08:03:05,860 restartedMain ERROR Unable to write to
> database [JdbcManager{name=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0,
> tableName=logs2, columnConfigs=[{ name=level, layout=%level,
> literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=null}] for appender
> [databaseAppender].
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.DbAppenderLoggingException:
> Failed to insert record for log event in JDBC manager:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
> Pozice: 20 [columnConfigs=[{ name=level, layout=%level, literal=null,
> timestamp=false }], sqlStatement=insert into logs2 () values (?),
> factoryData=FactoryData
> [connectionSource=ConnectionFactory@ca2c455,
> tableName=logs2, columnConfigs=[{ name=level, layout=%level,
> literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=null,
> immediateFail=false, retry=true, reconnectIntervalMillis=5000,
> truncateStrings=true], connection=HikariProxyConnection@1535828764
> wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@603942ae,
> statement=HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1512335087 wrapping insert into
> logs2 () values ('INFO'), reconnector=null, isBatchSupported=true,
> columnMetaData={}]

there is problem with not valid SQL INSERT statement:

> sqlStatement=insert into logs2 () values (?),

**Question: Do you have an idea why log4J doesn't compose the command correctly / completely? What's wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Log4j2.

I set up a quick project in IntelliJ, added the log4j2 2.14 api and core JARs and a database driver JAR and ran your code, and I was able to reproduce the incorrectly-formatted `INSERT` statement in your error message.

I used IntelliJ to download the log4j2 source JAR and attach it, and stepped through the code that put together the `INSERT` statement.  The method that adds the column names to the SQL string is called `appendColumnNames` and is in the class `JdbcDatabaseManager`.
It contains the following code, which I've abbreviated for clarity:

```java
        if (data.columnMappings != null) {
            for (final ColumnMapping colMapping : data.columnMappings) {
                // append column from colMapping
            }
            if (data.columnConfigs != null) {
                for (final ColumnConfig colConfig : data.columnConfigs) {
                    // append column from colConfig
                }
            }
        }
```

In this case we can see that column names from `ColumnConfig`s are not used if the `ColumnMapping`s are `null`.  This behaviour is incorrect: you should be able to specify `ColumnConfig`s only.  The second `if` should not be nested inside the first.

Log4j2 supports the use of `ColumnMapping`s as well as `ColumnConfig`s for specifying the columns to write to in your logging table, so one workaround is to use those instead.  An alternative workaround is to add the line

```java
        .setColumnMappings(new ColumnMapping[0])
```

to the construction of your `JdbcAppender`.  I made this change to your code and Log4j2 generated the correct SQL string.

Comment: Yes, in meantime I realized it too - I have to assign an empty ColumnMapping `final ColumnMapping[] columnMappings = new ColumnMapping[0];`