# Life of a Log4j logger and resources it uses

Tags: java, resources, log4j, lifecycle

I am new to `log4j` and need help understanding things about the logger instance. I define a logger in my class as a static member

```java
public static Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

A static member gets loaded into the memory when the class is loaded in memory by the JVM. If I am deploying my application as web service I am assuming the class will stay in the memory till the application is running. So that every time a request comes in , the application can immediately process it.

If i am using `FileAppender` or a `JDBCAppender` , would the file or database resources also be open throughout the life of the application.
Or does the log4j framework under the hood handle these resources differently/smartly.

If not , are there any guidelines / best practices for gracefully handling these resources when using log4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` <sup>**1**</sup> instead `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`. It is always easier to handle small files ... especially if an error occurs.

And I also recommend using `org.apache.log4j.DBAppender` <sup>**2**</sup> instead `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`.

See also:

- [Short introduction to log4j: Ceki Gülcü, March 2002](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
- [Log4j Best Practices](http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html)
- [Effective logging practices ease enterprise development [PDF]](https://geekdetected.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/effective-logging-practices-ease-enterprise-development.pdf)

---

*Notes*

1. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) is a sample configuration.
2. From [Apache Extras for Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/). You can download the file `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar). This appender uses a database schema (not customizable) and you can find it [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/log4j-extras/+/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/receivers/db/dialect/).  If you want to use other tables, you'll need to rewrite the appender. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670203/870248) is a sample configuration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out . Whats the idea behind logging to 3 diff tables ?

Comment: On the java docs I see both DBAppender and JDBCAppender use connection pooling. Are there other advantages of using DBAppender over JDBCAppender ?

Comment: Nope. You need to extends `JDBCAppender` in order to use connection pooling. See "For use as a base class:" in the [*javadoc*](http://bit.ly/1Bfoace).

Comment: The three tables are required. See the [*code*](http://pastie.org/pastes/10005474/text?key=ggkgajjrvbubgv4eky26rw) for this class.